# My game wont run after i build the game in unity but it runs on unity editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[SO this is the error that gives me on the console when i run the game in unity editor but the game works fine in the editor and when i press the error message on the console it takes me to another c# file named RigSyncSceneToStreamJob.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cv2C.png)

[this is where it shows the error is but in VsStudio it shows no issues.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz4Z0.png)

Answer (score 1):

for simple solution just make sure by check these variable is not null before execution
**job**,
**data**,
**job.rigStates**,
**data.rigStates**

because sometime the variable may be empty or null

For example

```
int jobLength = 0, dataLength = 0;
if(job != null && job.rigStates != null){
   jobLength = job.rigStates.Length;
}

if(data!= null && data.rigStates != null){
   dataLength = data.rigStates.Length;
}

// you statement
int count = Math.min(jobLength, dataLength);
```

Comment: Might prevent the exception but also hide an underlying implementation/design issue ;)